# UDF not always working - gets refreshed to [empty cell]

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I have the below UDF saved in a module in a workbook:

```
Function sumAbove(cel As Range) As Double
Dim firstCell As Long
Dim i As Integer

'Application.Volatile '(False)
firstCell = cel.Row

While Not cel.Offset((cel.Row - firstCell) * -1, 0).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    firstCell = firstCell - 1
Wend
sumAbove = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(firstCell + 1, cel.Column), cel))

ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
End Function
```

The function does work properly, however my issue is that the workbook somehow seems to "remove" the `sumAbove` from the worksheet.  I.e. I put `=SumAbove(b4)` and this calculates to `68`.  Great!  Then if I go into another sheet in the spreadsheet, add a chart, do things, etc. then go back, the cell will show  or `#Value!`   What's going on, why might it be doing this?

My workbook calculation is set to Auto, I added that `.EnableCalculation` which should help.

What's a little weird too, is that when the above UDF doesn't calculate properly, the following formula gives a `#Value` error:
`=IF(AND(A69<>"",D70<>""),TEXT(A69,"m/dd/yyyy")&" Average Row","")`  even though nothing in that formula is related to the `sumAbove` cell.  I have to go to the cell, hit `F2`, `Enter` and then it resolves to the right output.

What is possibly going on in my workbook?  Thanks for any ideas/advice!

Edit: Just to note - I do have two other UDFs, but none run on worksheet change or cell changes, they're just "regular" functions.  I've added `Application.Volatile (false)` to my UDFs, which doesn't change anything.  As @legendjr points out, I think it's due to Volatility somewhere...but the data in my page isn't changing at all, so even if a function was volatile, wouldn't the function just reset to its value?

Edit2: Maybe worth noting - when I am able to get `sumAbove` to work, only the cell I clicked into refreshed to the value...the other `sumAbove` cells just stay `#Value`

Comment: What other code do you have in the WB?

Comment: My guess would be there is a volatile formula in some other cell causing a recalculation of the workbook, and it is throwing this odd error out.  http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm

Comment: @Raystafarian - it's a few other `Sub`s and one or two other UDFs.  What's the best way to post them all? If I added to OP, it might just clutter everything...but I will if it's okay...

Comment: As long as none of them run on change events then we don't need them

Comment: @legendjr - is there any way to track down where the volatile formulas are? I'll look through that link you posted, thanks!  I know about Volatility in Excel, and even tried adding `Application.Volatile (False)` to my UDFs, but that didn't stop the refreshing.

Comment: Only way I know is to use find and search the entire workbook for those formulas in that article.  Good hunting!

Comment: The only thing I found was an `Indirect`.  However, it's in a "placeholder" cell, which stores my formula.  This is because as I use it, I paste the value it resolves to, but want to keep the formula somewhere so I can just drop it in if needed...Ah! I'll just add `'` before the placeholder, to see if that helps.

Comment: Hm, removed the `indirect` references, still get the refreshing "error".  Also, what would explain my non UDF function to return `#Value`? No cell in that formula refers to a cell with a UDF.  It seems like this happens especially when I delete a chart from a separate sheet?

Comment: Move your function to a new workbook (alone) and see what happens.

Comment: @Raystafarian - I moved it to another workbook and I can't seem to get it to reproduce the error I'm getting in my other WS.  I'll have a look through my UDFs and see what could be going on.